# Vue router - with links in a template string

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I import some text strings from a translation API. Some of these strings contain HTML - also links. Some of these links must link to internal router links. For example [some link](/foo). Clicking this link will ofcourse work - but it reloads the app, instead of pushing the link within the SPA.

What's the best method to make imported/external links act like vue-router links?

Comment: Are you using `<router-link>` to render the links?

Comment: No, it's just a big string, containing raw html. If I could override all click events on those, I could then call a method instead and use the content of the href attribute and then do a router.push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should be rendering the links with [`<router-link>`](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html) if you want the clicks to be handled by vue-router instead of by reloading the page.

Otherwise you can intercept the clicks (via delegation) and navigate to the new route manually:

```vue
<div @click="onClick">
  <!-- Render the HTML in here -->
  <a href="/foo/bar">Link</a>
</div>
```

```js
onClick(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Manually navigate to the route
    this.$router.push(e.target.href);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although it is an old question I ran into the same problem yesterday and might help for future reference.

Trying the way [@Decade Moon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50329698/10330567) answered did not solve my problem as the href tag of an anchor comes with the window.location.origin.

So if I was at https://www.example.com/about and want to navigate to the homepage I was getting this URL https://www.example.com/about/https://www.example.com which it was not the expected result.

So my solution was to **pass a data attribute in my template string**:

```
const toHomepage = `<span data-href="/">Link to Homepage</span>`;
```

And then in my component:

```
<p @click="linkTo" v-html="link"></p>
```

See that the **v-html directive will output my template string.**

```
linkTo(e) {
  if (e.target.dataset.href) {
    this.$router.push(e.target.dataset.href);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more sophisticated version of Decade's answer based on https://dennisreimann.de/articles/delegating-html-links-to-vue-router.html:

```
function onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
  let target = event.target as HTMLElement
  while (target && target.tagName !== 'A') {
    target = target.parentNode as HTMLElement
  }
  const href = (target as HTMLLinkElement).href
  if (target && target.matches("a:not([href*='://'])") && href) {
    const { altKey, ctrlKey, metaKey, shiftKey, button, defaultPrevented } = event
    if (metaKey || altKey || ctrlKey || shiftKey) { return }
    if (defaultPrevented) { return }
    if (button !== undefined && button !== 0) { return }
    if (target && target.getAttribute) {
      const linkTarget = target.getAttribute('target') as string
      if (/\b_blank\b/i.test(linkTarget)) return
    }
    const url = new URL(href)
    const to = url.pathname
    if (window.location.pathname !== to && event.preventDefault) {
      event.preventDefault()
      router.push(to)
  }
}
```